# Talend tLoop problem with conditions and nulls

Tags: while-loop, null, amazon-redshift, talend

I have a job which needs to insert a row (into Redshift) and then wait for another process to update a value in one of the fields.  The field is **null** to start, and as long as it stays **null**, the job waits and polls each minute.  When the field *is* updated: if it's 0, end - reporting success; if it's not 0, end - reporting failure.

I have the insert, the waiting (using a tLoop and Thread.sleep), and the querying the new row.

But I don't know how to structure my last step.  I have a tJavaRow where I check if the return_code is not null and set my looping condition to end the loop.  Then the **else** clause performs the sleep and then a **continue** statement.

From the tJavaRow I have three outputs:  One is to a tJava (empty, because I have to have an output), then two **if** conditions (flows) that just Close the RS connection (if rc = 0), or tDie (if rc != 0).

I am getting a **NullPointerException** (of course), but I suspect my approach is somehow off.

My question:  How do I fix the NullPointerExecption (if that's the real problem--probably not) or how do I change my job to accomplish what I want.  I mean "...want?"

image of the job:
[job current structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cqmq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close - if : `(rc != null && rc == 0)` 
tDie    - if :  `(rc != null && rc != 0)`

As far as I understand this issue, I hope this will work..

Comment: thanks!; that worked!
one caveat: in the IF flows in Talend, you don't actually use the word IF; Talend is building the code based on what you put into the components, and it will supply the IF keyword
btw, the exclamation marks just mean I was surprised that I didn't have a more fundamental issue with my code/construction; but I do appreciate this contribution

Comment: Yeah, just for understanding I have kept IF keyword. I have update the answer. :)